# This production C code seems to take the wrong branch sometimes

Tags: c, branch

There is this networking code which is being used in production on lots and lots of systems. One of our customers raised a bug, which happens on a specific powerpc machine. I've boiled down the root cause to this code (I've trimmed irrelevant stuff):

```
#define GThwU16(a,b) ((U16)((a) - (b)) < 0xFFFF/2 && a != b)
#define GET_VAR16(pos, var) do { checkWordBoundary(pos) ; var = *((U16 *)pos) ; pos = ((U16 *)pos) + 1 ; } while(0)
typedef unsigned short int U16;

static int decodeReceive(struct GplReceive *rec, GPLObject *objP)
{
  U16 sequenceNr;
  U32 linkId ;
  LinkHead *lh ;

  void *recIndexPtr = (((U8 *)rec) + objP->offset2startOfEGplSig) ;
  GET_VAR16(recIndexPtr, sequenceNr) ;
  GET_VAR32(recIndexPtr, linkId) ;
  lh = getLinkHead(linkId, objP) ;

  U16 savedSeq = sequenceNr;   // <- debugging variable added by me
  U16 savedTailR = lh->tailR;  // <- debugging variable added by me
  if(sequenceNr == lh->tailR) /* expected sequencenr? */
  {
    // some code
  }
  else if(GThwU16(sequenceNr, lh->tailR)) /* sequenceNr > lh->tailR */
  {
      // debugging logs added by me:
      ramlog_printf("decodeReceive:OOO:seqNo=%x expectedNo=%x\n", sequenceNr, lh->tailR);
      ramlog_printf("decodeReceive:OOO:savedseqNo=%x savedexpectedNo=%x\n", savedSeq, savedTailR);
  }
  // some other stuff
}
```

What we see in the logs is this:

```
[Mon May 25 20:34:14.260 2015] decodeReceive:OOO:seqNo=35da expectedNo=35da
[Mon May 25 20:34:14.260 2015] decodeReceive:OOO:savedseqNo=35da savedexpectedNo=35da
```

Any ideas?

PS: lh is an element in a dynamic array which lives in a controlling structure:

```
typedef struct GPLObjectTag
{
   //stuff
   struct LinkHeadTag **linkBase ; /* The base for the dynamic LinkHead array */
   //more stuff
} GPLObject ;
```

The controlling structure is allocated on the stack by a single process/thread which also calls decodeReceive:

```
OS_PROCESS(_gpl)
{
   GPLObject gplObj ;       /* create GPL object */
   fInitGPLObject(&gplObj, NULL) ;
   for(;;)
   {
      // receive signals from other processes 
      // call various worker functions depending on the signal
   }
}
```

Comment: Are threads involved?

Comment: Sort of, but not really. While the system is a RTOS, the lh->tailR is only accessed in a single process on a single core.

Comment: If any of the passed pointers of whatever the structure `lh` is part of can change concurrently with that code, you have potential races (i.e. undefined behavior according to the standard). There's no way to tell from the code you posted what is going wrong. Note that Power has a weaker memory model than e.g. x86, you're more likely to hit subtle race conditions there.

Comment: I've checked: lh is one element in a dynamic array which is pointed at by a pointer in a structure. Editing the code snippet above...

Comment: Basically, I don't think the gplObj (which contains lh) is even visible outside the current context.

Comment: GET_VAR16(recIndexPtr, sequenceNr) ; Is this using the pointer value as the sequence number? If so, does this allow for memory wrap? or High memory wit the top bit set? Is your linked list allocated in one block of memory are all entries allocated on need?

Comment: #define GET_VAR16(pos, var)   do { checkWordBoundary(pos) ; var = *((U16 *)pos) ; pos = ((U16 *)pos) + 1 ; } while(0)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "allowing for memory wrap" or "high memory with top bit set". The linkBase is always malloc()/realloc()ed with the operating system malloc() in increments of 16 LinkHeadTag's. If no space is left in the array, it is realloc()ed. There is no linked list.

Comment: What is `GThwU16()` and what does it do?

Comment: #define GThwU16(a,b) ((U16)((a) - (b)) < 0xFFFF/2 && a != b) Also, tailR is U16, and U16 is a short int.

Comment: have you tried printing the same logs but also before `if(sequenceNr == lh->tailR) `

Comment: No, that would mean printing a log line at every packet, which would overflow the available space in no time. This is an embedded system. I cannot know I am in the wrong branch until after entering the branch. And the wrong branch case is relatively rare.

Comment: I am assuming from the code that checkWordBoundary() does more that check the boundary, as the GET function acutally increments as well. So It looks like you are not handling the wrap on the buffer. It looks like you are using a fixed buffer (a UINT16 array?) and the code simply dos not take into account when the buffer is wrapped. i.e. when tail will be greater than head.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's just an assert for the least significant bits. I don't really understand what do you mean by "the code simply dos not take into account when the buffer is wrapped. i.e. when tail will be greater than head." What buffer are you referring to?